# how do I create an AVG bootable USB device from Linux?

Tags: linux, virus, anti-virus, virus-removal, avg-antivirus

Per [AVG instructions on creating a bootable USB device](http://www.avg.com/ca-en/226386):

```
Using the RAR/ZIP archive to create a USB bootable device

To create a USB flash drive variant of AVG Rescue CD, you will need to do the following:

    Extract the archive downloaded from AVG web to your preferred location.
    Double-click the extracted setup.exe file.
```

Without resorting to WINE, the USB bootable device can only be created from a Windows computer?

Comment: Usually you just have to copy the bootable image onto the USB stick, on Linux e.g. with `dd`. If the RAR/ZIP archive contains the bootable image itself, and if `setup.exe` is not needed to make changes to the image (or whatever), you should be able to do it from Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a multitude of Linux live "CD's" which can be installed with [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/):

> Supported Distributions
>
> UNetbootin has built-in support for automatically downloading and
>   loading the following distributions, though installing other
>   distributions is also supported:
>
> ```
> Ubuntu
> Kubuntu
> Xubuntu
> Lubuntu
> Debian
> openSUSE
> Arch Linux
> Damn Small Linux
> SliTaz
>
> Linux Mint
> Zenwalk
> Slax
> Dreamlinux
> Elive
> CentOS
> Mandriva
> FreeBSD
> NetBSD
>
> Fedora
> PCLinuxOS
> Sabayon Linux
> Gentoo
> MEPIS
> LinuxConsole
> Frugalware Linux
> xPUD
> Puppy Linux
> ```
>
> UNetbootin can also be used to load various system utilities,
>   including:
>
> ```
> Parted Magic
> SystemRescueCD
> Super Grub Disk
> Dr.Web Antivirus
>
> F-Secure Rescue CD
> Kaspersky Rescue Disk
> Backtrack
> Ophcrack
>
> NTPasswd
> Gujin
> Smart Boot Manager
> FreeDOS
> ```

While AVG isn't specified in that list, it looks do-able since Kaspersky is listed.